# BTRFS RAID6 array is broken, how do I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, hard-disk, raid, btrfs

I have a server running a btrfs raid 6 array which seems to have broken. When try to mount it I get the following error message. I don't know how or why it broke maybe a power outage or something (it happened during my vacation).

```
root@storage:/home/administrator# mount /dev/sdb /mnt/storage/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

I tried with `-o recovery,ro | -o degraded| -o clear_cache` all give the same error message.

When check dmesg this is the output.

```
BTRFS info (device sde): enabling auto recovery
BTRFS info (device sde): disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS: bdev /dev/sde errs: wr 1759, rd 0, flush 1091, corrupt 0, gen 0
BTRFS (device sde): parent transid verify failed on 17548820480 wanted 19215 found 18180
BTRFS (device sde): parent transid verify failed on 17548820480 wanted 19215 found 18180
BTRFS (device sde): parent transid verify failed on 17548820480 wanted 19215 found 18180
BTRFS (device sde): parent transid verify failed on 17548820480 wanted 19215 found 18180
BTRFS (device sde): parent transid verify failed on 17548820480 wanted 19215 found 18180
BTRFS (device sde): parent transid verify failed on 17548820480 wanted 19215 found 18180
BTRFS: error (device sde) in open_ctree:2897: errno=-5 IO failure (Failed to recover log tree)
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 11885 at /build/linux-SKpZC9/linux-3.19.0/fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c:137 btrfs_put_block_group+0x71/0x80 [btrfs]()
Modules linked in: iosf_mbi coretemp crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel ppdev aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw vmw_balloon gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd serio_raw vmwgfx ttm drm_kms_helper drm i2c_piix4 vmw_vmci shpchp 8250_fintek parport_pc parport mac_hid nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc autofs4 btrfs xor raid6_pq psmouse vmxnet3 mptspi mpt2sas raid_class scsi_transport_sas mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_spi pata_acpi
CPU: 0 PID: 11885 Comm: mount Tainted: G        W      3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu
Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 09/30/2014
 ffffffffc029dc10 ffff88002f0cfb88 ffffffff817c45cf 0000000000000007
 0000000000000000 ffff88002f0cfbc8 ffffffff81076a6a ffff88003a0fb000
 ffff88003bc34400 ffff88003bc34400 ffff88003a0fb080 ffff88003a0fb000
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff817c45cf>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
 [<ffffffff81076a6a>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8a/0xc0
 [<ffffffff81076b5a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
 [<ffffffffc01fd2d1>] btrfs_put_block_group+0x71/0x80 [btrfs]
 [<ffffffffc02078e8>] btrfs_free_block_groups+0x108/0x460 [btrfs]
 [<ffffffffc0216bb6>] open_ctree+0x1896/0x2090 [btrfs]
 [<ffffffffc01ecb10>] btrfs_mount+0x860/0x930 [btrfs]
 [<ffffffff811f8e88>] mount_fs+0x38/0x1c0
 [<ffffffff8119ce25>] ? __alloc_percpu+0x15/0x20
 [<ffffffff8121556b>] vfs_kern_mount+0x6b/0x120
 [<ffffffff812183be>] do_mount+0x21e/0xcb0
 [<ffffffff8121916b>] SyS_mount+0x8b/0xd0
 [<ffffffff817cb70d>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
---[ end trace 7bbd52ae33403cc9 ]---
BTRFS: open_ctree failed
```

I ran `btrfs rescue super-recover -y -v /dev/sdb` and also `btrfs rescue chunk-recover -y -v /dev/sdb`. When I run super-recovery it says everything is fine. Running chunk-recovery takes a long time but didn't fix anything that I could see.

The result from running `root@storage:/home/administrator# btrfs rescue chunk-recover -y -v /dev/sdb` can be found [here at pastbin](http://pastebin.com/WPPsWjQS) it's rather long

Comment: Just for clarity: this is the Btrfs built in RAID6 support not Btrfs on top of md-raid 6, isn't it?

Comment: @Anthon yes its the btrfs raid 6. I also tried removing a hardrive trying the moun degraded option which give the same error of wrong fs type

Comment: If you have a possibility to upgrade to  a 4.1 kernel (or boot from USB/CD with one) you should try that. IIRC Btrfs recommends to always have the latest kernel  when encountering problems.

Comment: Okay I'll try upgrading to a 4.1 kernel